# Google Script Editor in Google Sheets - Accept or Reject Email

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google Script Editor App Script V8 within Google Sheets and obtaining content using Google Forms. I wrote test code first to see how it would work before I went ahead and used it with actual information. I used the following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eduG0XZ9mDs. During the Step of "Publishing as a service", I used **Publish**, **Deploy as a Web App**, and I am able to create the url provided and input it but it is not in the format as in the video, which is the doc, instead it provides a script url as provided in the code. The code runs and sends the email but once you click on Accept or Reject, it does not open the document and notate the approval. I get an error as seen in the image below the code.

```
function sendEmail(e) {

var email = e.values[2];  
var town = e.values[1];
var appemail = e.values[3];

var url ='https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby8nLTy_qLYs2VIpv_pS1MF6mE1ZeVcYgrQN_6_6ewW95emGU_P/exec';

var approve = url + '&approval=true' + '&reply='+email;
var reject = url + '&approval=false' + '&reply='+email;

var html = "<body>"+
              "<h2>This is a test.</h2>"+
                town + " is where I am from!"+
                  "<p></p>"+ 
                "<a href ="+ approve +">Approve</a>"+"<br />"+
                "<a href ="+ reject +">Reject</a>"+"<br />"+
            "</body>";

  MailApp.sendEmail(appemail, "Approval Request", "Why no html?", {htmlBody: html});
}

function doGet(e) {

  var answer = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'You are from Trujillo Alto' : 'Try again';

  MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Trujillo Alto', 'You are from "+ answer);

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createHTML('<h2>An email was sent to '+ e.parameter.reply + answer ));
  return app
}
```

[Image after Accept or Reject button clicked in email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaYKr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

In order to remove your current error message, I thought that in your script, the link of query parameters is required to be a bit modified.

#### From:

```
var approve = url + '&approval=true' + '&reply='+email;
var reject = url + '&approval=false' + '&reply='+email;
```

#### To:

```
var approve = url + '?approval=true' + '&reply='+email;
var reject = url + '?approval=false' + '&reply='+email;
```

#### Note:

- By the way, when you modified the script for Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.
- `UiApp` has already been deprecated. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service) Also, please be careful this. If you want to display `'<h2>An email was sent to '+ e.parameter.reply + answer`, please modify as follows.

  - From:

    ```
      var app = UiApp.createApplication();
      app.add(app.createHTML('<h2>An email was sent to '+ e.parameter.reply + answer ));
      return app
    ```
  - To:

    ```
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h2>An email was sent to '+ e.parameter.reply + answer);
    ```

### Added:

About the error message of `Exception: The parameters (String,String) don't match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail. (line 26, file "Code")`, please modify as follows.

In your script, `"Trujillo Alto', 'You are from "+ answer` is not correct. In this case, please modify to `"Trujillo Alto", "You are from "+ answer`.

#### From:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Trujillo Alto', 'You are from "+ answer);
```

#### To:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Trujillo Alto", "You are from "+ answer);
```

#### Note:

When you modified the script for Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Comment: Thanks but now I get the following error with the changes...

Exception: The parameters (String,String) don't match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail. (line 26, file "Code")

Comment: @Berryblue Thank you for replying. I could confirm that from your replying, your issue of your question was resolved. I'm glad for it. And, I have to apologize. I couldn't notice that your script has one more error. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I added one more modification point. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Yes it worked, the only thing is that it doesn't do is updated the spreadsheet with an approval. However, you got it work! Thanks!

Comment: @Berryblue Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.